# Javascript code Function Explanation

Tags: javascript, html

The scenario is that i have an a drop down box as below

```
<td>Select Country:</td>
<td><select id="bcountry" name="bcountry"></select>
<script language="javascript">print_country("bcountry")</script></td>
```

I have an array of Countries in my JavaScript file

```
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania",....,"n);
```

now the below code of where this function is called from the html i dont really get it that how the below function is working

```
 function print_country(country_id)
{
// given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
option_str.length=0;
option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++)
        {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
    }
 }
```

Any one plz explain this above function print_country step by step to me

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some line numbers for the sake of discussion:

```
 function print_country(country_id)
 {
      // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
  1.    var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
  2.    option_str.length=0;
  3.    option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
  4.    option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
  5.    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++)
  6.    {
  7.         option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
  8.    }
 }
```

Line 1: The document object model (DOM) element is loaded into the variable `option_str`
Line 3: A new `Option("label","value")` object is created and assigned to `option_str`'s `options` array at index zero (0).
Line 4: The selected index is set to zero (0) which is the first element in the `options` array.
Line 5: You are looping from zero (0) to the length of `country_arr` and incrementing `i` each time.
Line 7: A new `Option("label","value")` object is created and assigned to `option_str`'s `options` array at the last position. The `Option` object contains the `i`th element in `country_arr` for both the label and the value.

Hope that clears it up!

Comment: This was actually a nice answer in that you were able to clean it up. Good idea using the line numbers!

Answer (score 0):

[Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/wCGat/):

- creates an empty `<select>` dropdown
- the script then makes a reference to your dropdown based on the id, given by `country_id`
- the script places an option with label "Select Country", a placeholder, as the first option with an empty string as a value.
- then it appends an `<option>` for each item in the `country_arr` array. Each of them use the same value for its label and its value.

Comment: thanx dear but whats the second parameter doing in this area while      'new Option('Select Country','');' the one after the select country

Comment: @KhanKoder remember that `<option>` tags have a label (the text you see) and a value (the actual value of the option). The first parameter is the label, the second is the value. `<option value="value">Label</option>`

Comment: See 

<option value="">Select Country</option>

Here value is empty string. This is decided by the second parameter which is ''.

Comment: @KhanKoder refer to this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option)

Answer (score 0):

I add comment in your code.

```
function print_country(country_id) // this is function declaration, have one parameter : country_id
{
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id); // Get the element in your html with the id equals to country_id, the element should be a dropdown list
    option_str.length=0 // clear the dropdown list item
    option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country',''); // add first item in dropdown list
    option_str.selectedIndex = 0; // set selected item to dropdown list
    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) // loop for the array
    {
        option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]); // create new item in your dropdown list
    }
 }
```

More :
[Javascript Select](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

1. Creates option_str, points it to country_id
2. Adds a header to it ("Select Country")
3. Then iterates through the country_arr array, and adds each country to the option_str control (ie, country_id).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the break-up explanation of the function `print_country`.

```
function print_country(country_id)
{
```

It signifies the start of function block for `print_country`.

```
var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
```

This statement simply gives a DOM element represented by `country_id`.

```
option_str.length=0;
```

The length of `option_str` is set to 0.

```
option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
```

First item in `option_str` is given an HTML `option` element with display value `Select Country` and real value an empty string.

```
option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
```

It sets the default value to the first option value, that is, 'Select Country'.

```
    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++)
```

It is a `for` loop over the array `country_arr`.

```
        {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
```

Now, in the first loop, the length of `option_str` is 1 as it has one element `Select Country`. So, `option_str` is assigned HTML `option` element over the loop array of `country_arr`.

```
    }
 }
```

Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

`country_id` being passed is the id of your selection box. This function retrieves the object in this statement:

```
var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
```

The length is being initialized to 0 initially and the default value for that is also set here:

```
option_str.length=0;
option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
```

By including the default option, the length is incremented by 1.
Then inside the loop options of countries is set till it reaches the end of the length of the `country_arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Without know where this function is being called from, here is what the function is doing:

```
 function print_country(country_id)
//function name with the argument "country_id". 
//Wherever this function is being called it is calling it as 
//"print_country('bcountry');
//the "bcountry" in the function call is found in the id of the <select /> tag in the HTML
{
// given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
//"option_str" is now the name of the <select /> object
option_str.length=0;
//setting the option_str length to 0 eliminates the <option /> tags that are normally
//a part of the <select />, essentially clearing the drawing board to avoid duplications
option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
//this command creates the first select <option/> giving the user the instruction to Select a country
option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
//now the selected <option />, the one that will appear in the <select> window is the instruction that was just created
    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++)
        {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
    }
//the "for" loop, above, cycles through the array and for each member of the Array it creates a new <option> for the <select> tag
 }
```

Comment: thanx this was also helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Assign the selectbox html object to the variable option_str.

```
var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
```

Set the number of options to 0. (In case there are any in the html I guess)

```
option_str.length=0;
```

Set the first option's value to 'Select Country'

```
option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
```

Set the default selected option to the first option.

```
option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Loop through the country_arr array.

```
for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++)
```

The following code will execute once for every item in the country_arry.

In javascript you can add any item to an array at any index with the following syntax:

```
myArray[index] = item
```

Ensuring the insert happens at the end of the array.

```
option_str.options[option_str.length]
```

Since arrays in javascript are 0 based, and the length property starts at 1, using option_str.length as the index ensures it will be inserted at the end of the array.

Insert the new option where the option text is the current item in the country_arr 
and the option value is also the current item in the country_arry

```
new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i])
```